# How to fix CSS in NextJS?

Tags: css, reactjs, markdown, next.js

I'm trying to work with markdown and facing issues with the css. I have reproduced the problem in the following link: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-quilljsbasic-forked-3rcxw?file=/src/App.js

Comment: What is the problem? please be more specific...

Comment: I'm trying to integrate markdown editor. While trying to integrate, the toolbar icons seems to have large size. How can I fix that and accomodate all toolbar icons in a single line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just set theme inside hook:

`const { quill, quillRef } = useQuill({ theme: "snow" });`

example:

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-quilljsbasic-forked-u2hep